# Timeout Error when deploying Ruby on Rails app with Capistrano to Windows Azure VM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, azure, capistrano, azure-virtual-machine

I'm new to Capistrano as well as Windows Azure and am having trouble deploying my Ruby on Rails app to my Azure Virtual Machine. I am able to log on and connect to the VM using SSH. Also, I successfully created a new Rails app while connected to the VM (was able to access it via the VM's DNS). However, I have no idea how to grab the Rails code from the VM server so I can edit it locally and then push the changes back up to the server.

Anyway, I created a simple Rails app locally and wish to deploy it (using Capistrano) to my Azure VM. I get the following error when I run `cap deploy` (and `cap deploy:setup`):

```
connection failed for: fb-shanghai.cloudapp.net (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2))
```

I keep playing around with the `deploy.rb` config file but keep getting the same error. Also, when I changed the `:web` role from the VM DNS "fb-shanghai.cloudapp.net" to the public VIP and ran `cap deploy`, I received a prompt to enter a password but no matter what I inputted, it failed.

At this point I'm really lost as to what I need to do in order to run my RoR app on my Azure VM. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

My environment:

- Mac OS X 10.7.5
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.9
- Using Ruby-Stack-1-9-3-6-Ubuntu-12-10 image for my VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to specify the VIP for the server configuration line:

So `server "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx", :web, :app, :db, primary: true`

Instead of `server "name_of_app.cloudapp.net", :web, :app, :db, primary: true`

Then, I needed to add `require "bundler/capistrano"` at the top of the `deploy.rb` file.

Finally, I followed some of the instructions from the [Capistrano wiki](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-from-the-beginning) as well as the [Ruby on Rails on Windows Azure tutorial](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-content/blob/master/DevCenter/Other/Tutorials/ruby-on-rails.md).

Comment: I too replaced `name_of_app.cloudapp.net` with IP address `xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but mine still wouldn't work with the IP instead of name_of_app.cloudapp.net. It took me a while to figure out, but for some reason Azure created the default public port to a random port number (not 22) when I created the VM so I edited it to 22 and it worked.

I should also mention that I used Bitnami rubystack from the VM depot to install my VM.

In terms of the deploy.rb file, I used this [gist](https://gist.github.com/3273427) file from the tutorial posted above.

Comment: if deploying a VM Depot image from the command line you can define the SSH port using the -ssh switch, e.g. "-ssh 22"

Comment: Which version of capistrano are you running? I'm having all kinds of issues with 3.x, I'm getting somewhere with 2.6.0 but getting -sh errors still...